# Find maximum number of characters that both strings have in common

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl, comparison

Find the maximum number of characters that both strings have in common. Characters are case sensitive, that is, lower case and upper case characters are considered as different.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string a, b;
    int number_cases = 0, count = 0;
    cin >> number_cases;
    while (number_cases != 0) {
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.size(); j++) {
                if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                    count++;
                    b[j] = '#';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << count << endl;
        count = 0;
        --number_cases;
    }
}
```

but it takes more than 1 second to run, I need to get it under 1 second or exactly 1 second. Any optimization tips?

Comment: This would be a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For starters, define "have in common".  Depending on the meaning, the simplest solution would be to just sort the strings, then do a diff on them.  (And how long are the strings?  Despite being O(n^2), I'd expect your code to finish almost instantly for normal length strings.)

Comment: is it from `currently running programming contest` http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/LCPESY ?  You mention `1 sec` . i think this should not be answered then .

Answer (score 2):

Just sort them both and use `set_intersection`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "Hello";
    std::string s2 = "World";

    std::sort(begin(s1), end(s1));
    std::sort(begin(s2), end(s2));

    std::string s3;
    std::set_intersection(begin(s1), end(s1), begin(s2), end(s2), std::back_inserter(s3));
    std::cout << s3.size() << ":" << s3;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f48efb17573586d3).

**Note**: if you are interested in the unique overlapping characters, it's possible to run `std::unique` on `s3`.

Comment: Is it case sensitive?

Comment: Yes (but that can be changed by passing an appropriate predicate)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there are only 256 characters. We can scan through each string once, and keep the count for each character in two arrays `int[]arrayA` for string A and `int [] arrayB` for string B.

Finally, iterate through both `int[] arrayA , arrayB` from 0 to 255, add to the result:

`result +=Min(arrayA[i],arrayB[i]);`

Time complexity will be O(n + m + 256) = O(n) with n and m is the length of string A and B

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "have in common", but for the
first definition that comes to my mind, the simplest solution is
probably to just use two arrays of `bool`:

```
bool inA[256] = {};
for ( auto current = a.begin(), end = a.end(); current != end; ++ current ) {
    inA[static_cast<unsigned char>(*current)] = true;
}
bool inB[256] = {};
for ( auto current = b.begin(), end = b.end(); current != end; ++ current ) {
    inB[static_cast<unsigned char>(*current)] = true;
}
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != 256; ++ i ) {
    if ( inA[i] && inB[i] ) {
        ++ count;
    }
}
```

But of course, this does something radically different than what
your code does.  If you're looking for the longest common
subsequence, or all of the subsequences, you'll need a different
algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
std::size_t count_letter_in_common_with_dup(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    std::size_t present1[256] = {};
    std::size_t present2[256] = {};

    for (unsigned char c : s1) {
        ++present1[c];
    }
    for (unsigned char c : s2) {
        ++present2[c];
    }
    std::size_t res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != 256; ++i) {
        res += std::min(present1[i], present2[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```